# Why am I getting 'undefined method `split' (NoMethodError)' when trying to copy 2 columns from CSV to another?

Tags: ruby, csv, split

I have a huge CSV containing 100+ columns. I want to copy 2 of those columns, the 53rd and the 91st, to another CSV to work with a smaller, more manageable CSV. Because the original CSV was delimited using commas, I wrote the following code to split it first, and then copy the 2 columns into a new CSV:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require 'csv'

fields=[]

class DateAndWeekColumns <
  Struct.new(:date, :weekday)
end

f=File.open('C:\Users\hp1\Desktop\Datasets\Columns-2.csv', "w") { |line|
    CSV.foreach('C:\Users\hp1\Desktop\Datasets\1433832864_210591.csv', "r") { |row|
        fields=row.split(',')
        data=DateAndWeekColumns.new
        data.date=fields[91]
        data.weekday=fields[53]
        line.push(data)
    }
}
```

But I keep getting the error `undefined method 'split' for #<Array:0x36f5e20> (NoMethodError)`. And the number inside `#<Array:` keeps changing every time I run the code. I guess this means that it is trying to put the contents of `split` into a new array instead of putting it in the `fields` array I have created for it, am I right? Or is it facing some issue when copying the contents of the array into the new CSV file? These are the 2 issues I can think of. I want to understand what is goin going here. How to solve the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`row` already has the data split by `,` to confirm it check this out

```
f=File.open('C:\Users\hp1\Desktop\Datasets\Columns-2.csv', "w") { |line|
    CSV.foreach('C:\Users\hp1\Desktop\Datasets\1433832864_210591.csv', "r") { |row|
        p row
    }
}
```

So you can change your code to

```
    data.date=row[91]
    data.weekday=row[53]
```

> And the number inside Array: keeps changing every time I run the code

Because `row` is an array, every time you rune the code it gets saved in different part of memory and the pointer to the place that is save gets changed

For example:

if the file is /tmp/data.csv:

```
r1_col1, r1_col2, r1_col3, r1_col4
r2_col1, r2_col2, r2_col3, r2_col4
```

Code:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'csv'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> CSV.foreach("/tmp/data.csv") do |row|
irb(main):003:1* p row
irb(main):004:1> end
["r1_col1", " r1_col2", " r1_col3", " r1_col4"]
["r2_col1", " r2_col2", " r2_col3", " r2_col4"]
=> nil
```

Comment: Ok, I tried this. Still, I get the exact same error.

Comment: Look at the example I provided.

Comment: So, you're saying that to copy the2 columns, I don't need to use split. Am I correct? Ok, so I removed the line `fields=row.split(',')`, and changed the code to  `data.date=row[91]` and `data.weekday=row[53]` like you said. Now I get this error: `undefined method 'push' for #<File:C:\Users\hp1\Desktop\Datasets\Columns-2.csv (closed)> (NoMethodError)`.

Comment: `line` is a file handler, if you want to save the records into a file you need to combine both data and save in into a third file. Have you consider using Excel? I suppose you can mvoe the data around easily by copying and pasting

Comment: The reason why I am having to do this coding is because my excel is huge, I can't open it. Its size is 30 GB.